# Why doesn't this recursive template work?

Tags: c++, templates

So I've tried to create what I thought would be a simple recursive template to generate a large but trivial nested type:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T, int N>
struct Nest
{
  using type = Nest<A<T>, N-1>
};

template <typename T>
struct Nest<T, 0>
{
  using type = T;
};

int main()
{
  typename Nest<A<int>, 20>::type x;
  std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(x).name());
};
```

The output of this program is

```
Nest<A<A<int> >, 19>
```

I was expecting to see a list of `A<int>` nested within 19 layers of `A<>`. What is happening here, and what do I have to do to get the effect I am looking for?

Comment: I have corrected my grave transgression. Some of the best code is written on the back of napkins. True story.

Comment: heh, sure: but "why does this code not work" with code that doesn't work for completely unrelated reasons (typo!) is often counter productive.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot the recursion step:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct Nest
{
  using type = Nest<A<T>, N-1>::type
};
```

May need a `typename` -- I don't have access to a compiler right now.

Comment: It is a bad answer. Please also write where `typename` is required. Beginners wouldn't know that by themselves.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the rules the `typename` keyword _is_ required because the template parameters to `Nest` force the assumption that the `::` precedes a _value_. Right?

Comment: It has been my experience that behaviour varies between compilers. Whether or not a given compiler accepts it without a given keyword is perhaps not a good indication that it is right.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cleanest way to do recursion like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct Nest:Nest<A<T>,N-1> {};
```

You can read the above as "A `Nest<T,N>` is a `Nest<A<T>,N-1>`" if you speak fluent C++.

We then add the exception:

```
template <typename T>
struct Nest<T, 0> {
  using type = T;
};
```

Next, us a `using` alias to get rid of `typename` spam elsewhere:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
using Nest_t = typename Nest<T,N>::type;

int main() {
  Nest_t<int, 20> x;
  std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(x).name());
};
```